# Como tomar y sacar a varias columnas los valores únicos con Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, variables

me encuentro buscando la forma de sacar los valores únicos de estas columnas para saber si son variables categóricas de la base de datos de Titanic:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuezUN/datasets/master/titanic.csv

```
categoricas = pd.unique(df[['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked']])
```

Y me sale este error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (891,9) into shape (891)
```

Me pueden ayudar con este error por favor.

Comment: puedes hacerlo así  `unicos = df.apply(lambda x: x.unique())`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes iterar por cada columna y ver los valores columna por columna, por ejemplo:

```
for col in df_titanic.columns:
  print(df_titanic[col].unique())
```

Puedes imprimirlo o almacenarlo en alguna colección eso ya a tu elección.